# Continuous operator $E$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $E: C_b^1(\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R) \rightarrow C_b^1(\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R) $

where

$$(Ef)(x_1,x_2):=  \begin{cases} f(x_1,x_2) & \text{ if }x_1\ge0 \\
\alpha f(-x_1,x_2) + \beta f(-0.5x_1,x_2) & \text{ if }x_1 \lt 0\end{cases}$$

> Give values for $\alpha$ and $\beta $ and prove that $E( C_b^2(\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R)) $ is not a subset of $C_b^2(\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R)$

What I got so far:

$E(f)$ has to be continuous in $0$ which leads me to the following equation:

$$\alpha +\beta =1$$

$E(\frac{d}{d_{x_1}}f)$ has to be continuous in 0 which leads to the equation:
$$-\alpha+-\frac{1}{2}\beta =1$$

Combining the two I get: $\alpha =-3  \quad \beta=4$

Continuing the same "thing" for $f \in C^2$

$$\alpha+\frac{1}{4}\beta=1=-2$$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: This is confused.  The title asks about a *continous* (sic) operator $R$, but the body does not define such an operator.  Even if we were to accept that the Question reflects a problem about continuity of mapping $E$, or about items in the range of $E$, the quoted problem is apparently about a lack of continuity (perhaps of higher degree?).  Please edit for clarity, and take the time to provide context for the problem (why is it of interest? what approach did you consider? etc.).

Comment: @hardmath The title was a typo. With that particular problem, I don't know where to start. (Found this problem in a book with no additional context). For the first part of the problem, I think I have to use the continuity and differentiability of $f$ to find values for $\alpha, \beta$ but that doesn't get me anywhere